# Bounded derivative

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am studying a chapter on Lipschitz condition. I am stuck with what it means to say "bounded first derivative". I searched about it in the internet but couldn't find anything. Could someone please tell me about what it means and give some examples?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "bounded first derivative"=the first derivative (which is a function) is bounded..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that there exist constants $m$ and $M$ such that $f'(x)$ always satisfies $m\leq f'(x) \leq M$. The idea is that, in Lipschitz continuity, the difference $f(x)-f(y)$ is bounded by linear functions of $x-y$, which is equivalent to saying that the derivative must be bounded where it exists (and, with some more work, that the derivative exists almost everywhere), since if it were not bounded, the quotient $\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$ would have to be unbounded as well, from the definition of a derivative, meaning that every Lipschitz continuous function has a bounded derivative and every function with a bounded derivative is Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: Although in practice, we usually simplify it to a single constant $M\ge 0$ such that $|f'(x)|\le M$

Answer (score 3):

Let $f$ be a function. $f$ has bounded first derivative if the function $f'$is [bounded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_function).